# JQuery UI Autocomplete Multiple Textbox on ASP MVC Razor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, razor

I return a class object but only XRCFOR textbox is populate correctly. Select events seems no work.
Through a WebServe I return  object items. Select event on a row however is only populated the XRCFOR textbox. Here is the Html/razor/Jquery code. Thanks.

```
<td>
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.XRUDBF, Functions.GetAdditionalViewData(ViewData["PageStatus"].ToString(), ViewData["PageReadonly"].ToString(), "form-control"))
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.XRCFOR, Functions.GetAdditionalViewData(ViewData["PageStatus"].ToString(), ViewData["PageReadonly"].ToString(), "form-control"))
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.XRCFORDescription, new {htmlAttributes= new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" }})
    <script type="text/javascript">                        
                $("#XRCFOR").autocomplete({
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/Zoom/GetFOR/",
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: { term: request.term },
                            success: function (data) {
                                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                    return {
                                        label: item.B5CFOR + " - " + item.B5RGS1, value: item.B5CFOR
                                    };
                                }))
                            }
                        })
                    },
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        $("#XRUDBF").val(ui.item.B5CUDB);
                        $("#XRCFOR").val(ui.item.B5CFOR);
                        $("#XRCFORDescription").val(ui.item.B5RGS1);
                    },
                    //messages: {
                    //    noResults: '',
                    //    results: function () { }
                    //},
                    minLength: 1
                });
    </script>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this solution

```
success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.B5CFOR + " - " + item.B5RGS1, value: item.B5CFOR, extravalue: item
                            };
                        }))
                    }
```

and then

```
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#XRUDBF").val(ui.item.extravalue.B5CUDB);
            $("#XRCFORDescription").val(ui.item.extravalue.B5RGS1);
        },
```

works fine!